# Is a copy-on-return operation executed prior or after lock_guard destructor?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, destructor, race-condition, stdmutex

Is the `get_a()` function safe for race-conditions or do I need to explicitly copy `str_` as in `get_b()` in order to have a thread-safe function?

```
class Class {
public:
  auto get_a() -> std::string {
    auto&& guard = std::lock_guard{mutex_};
    return str_;
  }
  auto get_b() -> std::string {
    auto&& guard = std::lock_guard{mutex_};
    auto str = str_;
    return str;
  }
private:
  std::mutex mutex_{};
  std::string str_{};
};
```

*Note: I'm aware that there are similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but I could not find one which explicitly answers this question.*

Comment: Prior, I believe

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[[stmt.return]p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#3):

> The copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced before the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression established by the operand of the `return` statement, which, in turn, is sequenced before the destruction of local variables of the block enclosing the `return` statement.

This means that the following happen in order:

1. The return object is copy-initialized
2. Any temporaries inside the return statement are destroyed
3. Local variables are destroyed

So, we can infer that `get_a` is completely safe.