# Does a lock_guard protect the return value?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I have a question about `lock_guard`s and return values. I would like to illustrate my question with some code:

```
class Semaphore
{
public:
    Semaphore() = delete;
    Semaphore(int n);

    /**
     * Increases semaphore by one.
     */
    void up()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_);
        ++n_;
    }

    /**
     * Decreases semaphore by one.
     */
    void down()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_);
        --n_;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the underlying value of the semaphore.
     */
    int get1() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_);
        int tmp = n_;
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the underlying value of the semaphore.
     */
    int get2() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_);
        return n_;
    }

private:
    mutable std::mutex m_;
    int n_;
};
```

The above class is a simple implementation of a `Semaphore`. Which of the get-methods is thread-safe? Is `get2` good enough or do I have to use `get1`? Do I have to copy the internal value `n_` to a temporary variable or can I just return it right away?

This post boils-down to the question: **Does the lock_guard protect my return value?**

Comment: I'm sure I already have found a duplicate of this question. But the answer is yes, the `std::lock_guard` will be destroyed after the return.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: [Is a copy-on-return operation executed prior or after lock\_guard destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613641/is-a-copy-on-return-operation-executed-prior-or-after-lock-guard-destructor) except that `get1()` and `get2()` are replaced by `get_a()` and `get_b()` :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get2()` is sufficient to protect the return value.

`n_` is returned by value, therefore a copy of the variable is made to return to the caller with your `return n_` statement. Your `lock_guard` will make sure that the `n_` won't get changed until that copy is returned to the caller after which it gets destroyed thus releasing the lock.

Returning a copy is not incorrect, but will not give you any added benefits. Further in any case you need to maintain the lock until the copy is returned too. Therefore with `get1` you pay for an additional copy assignment withouth much gain unless the compiler optimizes it out.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are equal. Return value is created before `std::lock_guard` is destroyed.

You can test this with next code snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

template <typename T>
struct GuardWrapper : std::lock_guard<T> {
    GuardWrapper(T &e) : std::lock_guard<T>(e) { std::cout << "Creating guard" << std::endl; }
    ~GuardWrapper() { std::cout << "Deleting guard" << std::endl; }
};

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "Creating A" << std::endl; }
    A(const A& other) {
        *this = other;
        std::cout << "Copying A" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A() { std::cout << "Deleting A" << std:: endl; }
};

struct B {
    A test() {
        GuardWrapper<std::mutex> guard(m_);
        return a_;
    }
    A test_with_tmp() {
        GuardWrapper<std::mutex> guard(m_);
        A tmp = a_;
        return tmp;
    }

   private:
    std::mutex m_;
    A a_;
};

int main () {
    std::cout << "init" << std::endl;
    B b;
    std::cout << "try without temp" << std::endl;
    A a0 = b.test();
    std::cout << "try with temp" << std::endl;
    A a1 = b.test_with_tmp();
    std::cout << "cleanup" << std::endl;
}
```

output is

```
init
Creating A
try without temp
Creating guard
Copying A
Deleting guard
try with temp
Creating guard
Copying A
Deleting guard
cleanup
Deleting A
Deleting A
Deleting A
```